# What is the most secure way of encrypting/decrypting data?

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, .net-4.0

Now I know that is a very open question such as "How long is a piece of string" but I am a newbie to this game.

From my basic understanding (before I delve into this subject) I believe AES 256bit encryption is very secure.

My needs are to generate private and public keys using .Net using the most secure encryption possible.

Now I know from an experts point of view this maybe a naive question but please help me expand my knowledge and suggest the best approaches, algorithms and anything else to consider in this type of project.

Many thanks.

Comment: To put it bluntly: As long as *you* do it, it won't be secure. As Bruce Schneier writes: "Ciphers are hard. Cryptography is hard. Ciphers are the easy part." Learn about the subject and use a high-quality library. *Your code* will be the weak link, not the cipher.

Comment: Your question displays a lack of understanding of crypto. This means that you *will not* implement it properly, and it *will* be broken. I get crypto wrong all the time and I've been at it for *years*. I'd suggest you at least read some literature on basic cryptographic principles before trying to meddle with such things.

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you saying that something like the .Net libaries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged%28v=VS.90%29.aspx are weak?

Comment: Basic [google query](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=asymmetric+cryptography+c%23) shall get you started

Comment: @Jon: No, the libraries are almost certainly fine. What I'm saying is that as long as you don't have a firm grasp on the subject, you are very likely to design a system with flaws that are much, much easier to exploit than any weakness in the library. (Since this very fact itself is the first lesson of cryptography, I'm tempted to conclude that you are not yet at that level.)

Comment: @KerrekSB - I am reminded of the old KGB code-breaker motto: "It is easier to break fingers than it is to break codes".

Comment: Why does every encryption question end up in "more knowledgeable folk" shooting them down? He asked to find out.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no such thing available. Your level of encryption should be proportional to the thread associated with the data. Keep in mind that usually anything created by human, can be broken by human.

If you want to use a pair of keys to encrypt/decrypt data, you are most likely on a path to asymmetric cryptography - [google it](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=asymmetric%20cryptography%20c#). From the .NET point you can take a look at the implementation of [RSA algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx), which is [considered to be secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem) for the key size of <s>1024</s> 2048 bit or more.

Comment: In that case the RSA is more secure than SHA512?

Comment: SHA512 is a **hashing** algorithm, not encryption (meaning SHA512 is only one way). You will not be able to restore an object from hash as this operation is not reversable. You can probably compare AES with RSA, but that depend on your objective, data, and the processes

Comment: Your question cannot be answered. They are both secure depending on how you use them and what sort of data your encrypting will determine which one will secure the data more. Any data you can decrypt meaning having to store the process to encrypt and decrypt in the same location. This fact means anyone with access to that process can decrypt your information.  The fact you think SHA512 is an encrypting algorithm proves you should do some additional research.

Comment: @oleksii: If SHA512 is one way only, how is that website working exactly? It can be used to encrypt and decrypt : http://sha2decrypt.com/

Comment: @ibiza well spotted, well that's brute force really, as it says in the about page - "SHA2Decrypt provides a web interface to a database containing 2436860 SHA-2 hashes...". So they take any string, calculate hash and give users fast access to both strings. Please take a look at the number of strings already available - 2436860 that is nothing, given I have a string of just 100 chars, the chances that this db has my string are nearly zero, or in words of math: 1 / (256 (say all possible ASCII symbols) ^ 100 (possible combination in a string of 100 chars))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need encryption to generate public/private keys. It's a mathematical operation. The keys are then used for encryption.

A quick overview of how they all link together is that

1. The keys are generated.
2. The keys are then used to securely exchange a 'password' between the parties.
3. The 'password' is then used to encrypt further communication between the two parties.

Part 2 would use schemes such as hashing and signing to ensure the communications are authentic and untampered.
PKI is quite slow so although you could in practice use it to secure communications it's typically only used at the beginning and then the faster schemes such as AES are used.

A lot of this should be on Wikipedia and also check out Bruce Schneier's work.

Answer (score 0):

AES is a symmetric algorithm -- meaning one key ... if you want key pairs lookup the RSA libraries .... a quick google search provides the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx